# Добавление таблицы в SQLite

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Создал таблицу `article` и добавил ее в `settings.py` вот так:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'article', # моя табличка
]
```

Далее ввожу в терминал `python manage.py migrate` и у меня показывает, что команда выполнена успешно. Но когда я открываю БД, то таблицы `article` просто нет. Почему ?

И это при том, что если в файле `models.py` сделать ошибку, то команда `python manage.py migrate` не отработает, а значит все указал верно, разве нет ?

Comment: `makemigrations` сделали?

Comment: нет, а что это такое ?

Comment: Суть в том, что чтобы мигрировать, нужно сначала создать миграцию на основе внесенных изменений в моделях. Соответственно нужно командой `makemigrations` создать миграцию (без аргументов команда создаст миграции для всех приложений), а уже потом делать `migrate`. [документация](http://djbook.ru/rel1.9/topics/migrations.html)

Comment: Собственно, парой вопросов ранее я это всё уже рассказывал.)